# Integrating the gaussian kernel on unbounded curves in $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, gaussian-integral

It is well known (e.g. using Fourier transform) that if $\beta\in\Bbb C$ with $\Re\beta>0$, then
$$
\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-bu^2}\,du=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta}}\;.
$$
Once chosen a branch for the square root, by the variable change $\sqrt\beta u=w$ we get
$$
\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_{\sqrt\beta\Bbb R}e^{-w^2}\,dw=1\;.
$$
Now, $\sqrt\beta\Bbb R$ is a straight line in $\Bbb C$. Does this holds true on more generic curves in $\Bbb C$ which are diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R$? For example, if $h\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is $\mathscr C^1$, bounded with $h'(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$, if we consider the curve
$$
\Gamma:=\{x+ih(x)\;:\;x\in\Bbb R\}
$$
Does
$$
\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_{\Gamma}e^{-z^2}\;dz=1
$$
hold true?

Comment: Let $F(z)$ be the primitive of $e^{-z^2}$ such that $F(0)=0$. Then for any $\epsilon >0$, $\lim_{|z|\to \infty, |arg(\pm z)|\le \pi/2-\epsilon} F(z)= \sqrt{\pi}/2$.

Comment: @reuns: thanks answering, but it's absolutely not clear to me why that limit holds.  I would be grateful if you give me a hint about this.

Comment: Because  $e^{-z^2}$ tends uniformly exponentially fast to $0$ when $|z|\to \infty$ in this region, so $F(z)\to F(\pm \infty)= \sqrt{\pi}/2$ as $|z|\to \infty$ in this region

Comment: Of course I meant $|arg(z^2)|\le \pi/2-\epsilon$ ie. $|arg(\pm z)|\le \pi/4-\epsilon$

Comment: I see. Thank you!